# Can I help Nat and Meghyn find hearty truffles?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

While traveling around Hyrule, I’ve repeatedly run into two sisters Nat and Meghyn. After rescuing them from Bokoblins, they say that they’re searching for hearty truffles.

> **Nat**: Remember, Meghyn, nobody goes home until we find those hearty truffles!
>
> **Meghyn**: *sigh* She’s right. The sooner we find those truffles, the sooner this will all be over with.

Their dialogue makes it seem like there should be some way to help them search, but I haven’t been able to find any way to do this.

Is there any way to help Nat and Meghyn find hearty truffles?

Comment: From what I could remember, there's no quests associated with them at all. Probably just a hint to you that there's supposedly truffles in the area or they're completely wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to help them find the hearty truffles.

First, I completed all side quests in the game as indicated by the side quest counter. There was no quest related to finding the truffles for them.

Second, I tried various things which include dropping hearty truffles next to them, throwing hearty truffles at their heads, eating hearty truffles right next to them, building a camp fire and roasting hearty truffles next to them.

Players have been discussing this in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632936-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75115960?page=1) without a conclusion.

In addition, this [Wiki site about Hearty Truffles](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hearty_Truffle) states:

> The female Hylian traveler Nat loves Hearty Truffles and often drags
>   her sister Meghyn around Hyrule to search for them, often leading to
>   them to be attacked by Bokoblins while forging for them. Link can
>   defeat the Bokoblins to rescue them and will be rewarded with a random
>   item or Rupees provided neither girl is knocked out, **however Link is
>   unable to help them actually search for Hearty Truffles**.

Comment: Are there usually hearty truffles nearby when finding Nat and Meghyn?

Comment: There is a slightliy higher chance to find some truffles when they are around, but this is only because they often look for truffles in small forests where truffles (at least regular ones) are more likely to be found anyways. If you are looking for a source of hearty truffles you can check the wiki link in my post above. You can even buy them from [Giro](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Giro). But he only has 2 of them in stock.